# Launch Tomcat using Puppet

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I am trying to launch tomcat using Puppet:

```
exec { "start-tomcat":
  user    => $test_user,
  cwd => "$tomcat_directory/bin/",
  command => "sh catalina.sh start"
}
```

but I receive an error:

> change from notrun to 0 failed: sh catalina.sh start returned 1 instead of one of [0]

Can someone please explain me how can I do this? By the way, it's starting correctly when I do it manually.

Comment: Seems I've got an idea, `user    => $test_user,` this line does not mean that will be used specified user $HOME, so my next question is how can I launch it as real user?

Comment: I found one more point, seems that .bashrc that I've prepared in previous steps is not available for puppet exec, please help me launch exec with .bashrc of of the user.

Comment: isn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571735/sh-startup-sh-start-tomcat-with-puppet-module the same as your question ?